# ComboBoxes on Excel UserForm dependant vba created lists need to keep original

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a UserForm which gets the unique values from three columns in a table when it loads and creates the lists for 3 comboboxes. City, Building and Account. 
If the user first selects a city, then the possible buildings for that city are shown in the "Building" . Like wise if the first select a building(some cities have buildings with the same name), the city list changes and the account code changes. 
However if they select a city and then select a building I lose the city list. 
I need to be able to select a city, then a building, and then change my mind and select a city based on the building name. Likewise accounts are used at more than one location so if i select a city, then an account and then want a different city for that account I lose my other lists.

The City_change runs when the user selects a city, and the FilterCity runs whent the form opens and within the City_change sub.

```
Private Sub City_change() 'When the user selects a city, the list of buildings and cost centres changes to only those previously used in that city
'declare the variables

    ASM = ThisWorkbook.Name
    'error handling
   ' On Error GoTo errHandler:

   strSelect = Me.City.Value
   strSelect1 = Me.Building.Value

   Workbooks(ASM).Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1") _
   .Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=Me.Controls("City").Value 'Auto filter the register to the selected city

            FilterBuilding
        'change cost centre list
            FilterCostCentre
            'clear the filter on the register to allow another change
            With Workbooks(ASM).Worksheets("Database")
                If .ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.FilterMode = True Then
                .ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                End If
            End With
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub FilterCity()

'Declare Variables.
Dim Coll As Collection, cell As Range, LastRow As Long
Dim blnUnsorted As Boolean, i As Integer, temp As Variant
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet

ASM = ThisWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(ASM).Worksheets("Database").Rows(1).Hidden = True
'Populate the ListBox with unique Make items from column
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Coll = New Collection
        'Open a With structure for the ListBox control.
        With City
        .Clear
        For Each cell In Workbooks(ASM).Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(17). _Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'Only attempt to populate cells containing a text or value.
        If Len(cell.Value) <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Coll.Add cell.Text, cell.Text
        If Err.Number = 0 Then .AddItem cell.Text
        End If
        Next cell

        'Sort the ListBox items in ascending order.
        blnUnsorted = True
        Do
        blnUnsorted = False
        For i = 0 To UBound(.List) - 1
        If .List(i) > .List(i + 1) Then
        temp = .List(i)
        .List(i) = .List(i + 1)
        .List(i + 1) = temp
        blnUnsorted = True
        Exit For
        End If
        Next i
        Loop While blnUnsorted = True
        'Close the With structure for the ListBox control.
        End With

        Set Coll = Nothing
Workbooks(ASM).Worksheets("Database").Rows(1).Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You could have a reset button perhaps.

Comment: @SLR - There is a reset button, I'm trying to cover all the potential for users doing things out of sequence

Comment: But how will Excel know that a user has changed their mind? You will need to restrict their choices by e.g, hiding the 2nd box until the 1st box has been done.